# Telerik Kendo UI ClientTemplate syntax breaking when upgraded the existing .NetMvc Kendo UI version from 2019.2.619 to 2023.1.117

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

In KendoUI version 2019.2.619, the below syntax is working fine but when it upgraded to 2023.1.117, the page is breaking with below error in browser console.
Existing code
`columns.Template(p => p.date).Title("Date").Width("25%").ClientTemplate("#=DateStr#")`;`

The error displayed in the browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid template:'#=DateStr#' Generated code:'var $kendoOutput, $kendoHtmlEncode = kendo.htmlEncode;with(data){$kendoOutput=''+(DateStr)+'';}return $kendoOutput;'
    at Object.compile (kendo.all.js:313050:21)
    at kendo.all.js:313050:21
    at c (kendo.all.js:313050:21)
    at init._rowsHtml (kendo.all.js:313050:21)
    at init._renderContent (kendo.all.js:313050:21)
    at init.refresh (kendo.all.js:313050:21)
    at init.trigger (kendo.all.js:313050:21)
    at init._process (kendo.all.js:313050:21)
    at init.success (kendo.all.js:313050:21)
    at success (kendo.all.js:313050:21)
```

Tried the use Template() instead of ClientTemplate but then whole page is crashing without any console error.

Comment: The above syntax is failing only when we added our content security policy in which we have removed unsafe-eval and just kept unsafe-inline for script-src, else it is working fine if we include the unsafe-eval in the content security policy